# Change text to input on a row

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change a text into an input when the user clicks on the update button. It will change all the text in 1 row. Below is the example that I made. How to change all the text to input? I am able to make the text hidden but stuck to change it all to input.

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.upd');
var tableColumn = document.querySelectorAll('td'),
  rows;

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var span = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('span');

    for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
      span[i].style.display = 'none';
      text = span[i].innerHTML;
    }

    // Create an input
    input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.value = text;
    input.size = Math.max(text.length / 4 * 4, 4);
    rows = this.parentNode.parentNode.children;
    // console.log(rows[0].children[0]);
    rows[0].children[0].parentNode.insertBefore(input, rows[0].children[0]);

  });
}
```

```css
td,
tr,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>remark</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>text 1</span></td>
      <td><span>text 2</span> </td>
      <td><span>text 3</span></td>
      <td><span>text 4</span></td>
      <td>
        <button class="upd">Update</button> <button>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: make it simpler by pre-generating input tags that would help cleanup the code and js logic. I have added an example code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take care not to implicitly create global variables. Iterate over every `td`, hiding the `span` and creating `input`s accordingly. Also, since the `span`s contain *text*, you should use `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`:

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.upd');
var tableColumn = document.querySelectorAll('td'),
  rows;

for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const tds = button[i].parentElement.parentElement.children;
    [...tds].forEach((td) => {
      const span = td.children[0];
      span.style.display = 'none';
      const text = span.textContent;
      const input = td.appendChild(document.createElement('input'))
      input.value = text;
      input.size = Math.max(text.length / 4 * 4, 4);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
td,
tr,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>remark</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>text 1</span></td>
      <td><span>text 2</span> </td>
      <td><span>text 3</span></td>
      <td><span>text 4</span></td>
      <td>
        <button class="upd">Update</button> <button>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and detail. May I know what does dot (.) on `[..tds].forEach`  means.

Comment: It converts the `tds`, an `HTMLCollection`, into an array. Arrays can be iterated over with `forEach`, unlike `HTMLCollection`s. (`forEach` or other array methods are often preferable over `for` loops - better abstraction, no manual iteration, function composability and scope) `[...arrayLikeVar]` is similar to `Array.from`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.upd');
var tableColumn = document.querySelectorAll('td'),
  rows;

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var span = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('span');

    for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
      //span[i].style.display = 'none';
      text = span[i].innerHTML; 
            span[i].innerHTML = ' ';

            // Create an input
            input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.value = text;
            input.size = Math.max(text.length / 4 * 4, 4);

            span[i].appendChild(input);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple by including *input* elements as part of HTML output, right after *span*. Use the following functions below to toggle b/w them.

```
function onClickShowInput(evt) {
    evt.target.className = 'hide'
    evt.target.nextElementSibling.className = ''
}
```

Similarly on blur from input show span.

```
function onBlurShowSpan(evt) {
    evt.target.className = 'hide'
    evt.target.previousElementSibling.className = ''
}
```

Finally attach the related events.

```
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(span => span.addEventListener('click', onClickShowInput))
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', onBlurShowSpan))
```